# not able to exports function in other file

Tags: javascript, node.js, export

I have written one function in the file and wants to call it from another file. Both files are in the same folder.

.
├── member.js
├── universal.js

```
member.js

function getRandomNo(min,max){
  return Math.random() * (max-min) + min;
}

module.exports.getRandomNo=getRandomNo;
```

Accessing it in universal.js as

```
const modelUniversal = require('./universal.js');
```

//somewhere inside a function

```
modelUniversal.getRandomNo(a,b);
```

but I am not able to call the `getRandomNo` function. I am running the script using nodemon, pm2.

But when I try to run using node universal.js, it is working. Why?

How to get rid of this problem?

node -v 
v8.9.1

npm -v
5.5.1

Comment: Can you please give more details on "//somewhere inside a function"? I feel that is where the problem is. Rest all looks fine to me.

Comment: @SagarGopale actually I even try to log the modelUniversal const after assigning it.Then also it prints empty array.

Comment: @SagarGopale "somewhere inside a function" that a simple function

Comment: If it is a simple function then the above code works for sure. Paste the error here, which you are getting.